# Unable to Access the properties file from out side the Directory- run the Jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

1. I have used properties file in my java application and access that inside the static block.

---

```
static {

     try {
  properties = new Properties();

 properties.load(new FileInputStream("Test.properties"));

       } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();

   }
```

create and run the jar file via command prompt able to access the  properties file from where the jar file located directory

Example: E:\test\ java-jar MyApplication.jar  --> this is jar located directory. this way is working correctly

2. I would like to run this jar file from  other directory like as

   Example: D:\result ---> other directory. Now i run the jar from this directory.
3. I tried to run used this command in prompt.

   Example: D:\result\ java-jar  E:\test\ MyApplication.jar
4. I got an

---

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Test.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

      at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)

      at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)

      at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)

     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)

    at MyApplication.<clinit>(MyApplication.java:47)
```

5. How to access the properties file while run that jar file from outside the directory?

Comment: is this wroking from same directory? n Please share Project hierarchy and location of properties file?

Comment: no,different directory.

Comment: Have you viewed the Jar , does it have `Test.properties`?

Comment: @RameshC ya i know you want to run from different directory but i am asking about is this working from same directory.?? Because this problem i divide into two part one is test.proprieties file location and other system path to execute jar from other location

Comment: want working from same directory?, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the folder which hosts Test.properties to the CLASSPATH.
In this case, E:\test\ should be added to the CLASSPATH.